# Meaning of linear

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is a linear function and $0<a<b$,  then $\int_a^b f^{\prime\prime} \left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=$

I am confused by the word ** linear**

If it means the power of the function then the answer is zero

But if it means $e^{x^2}+\sin\left(x\right)$ then is just the first derivative of the function at b minus the first derivative of the function at a

Comment: Unless it is being used in a non-standard way, linear means $f(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$

Comment: Or even $\,f(x)=ax+b\,$ , which is also called "liner" in analytic geometry and sometimes even in calculus, though not in linear algebra

Comment: It  looks like a poorly worded problem. If that is all in the problem just go with the simplest answer, namely $0$, and move on to the next problem. The given inequality does not seem to play any role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a standard intro calculus class, I suspect a linear function is a function that describes the graph of a line, i.e. a function of the form $f(x) = ax + b$ for some $a,b$.

A little bit further on, a linear function is a function such that when you double the input, the output is also doubled (and in particular $f(cx) = cf(x) )$. This means the function is of the form $f(x) = ax$.

Although I'm uncertain which definition of linear applies here, they both yield the same answer.